# Adding quotes to a particular word in string

Tags: ruby, string, double-quotes

I have a string that has a value that I want to be in quotes. Following is the text which I currently have:

```
text = "#{value1} has viewed your #{value2}"
```

I want `value2` to be in quotes. I want:

```
text = ""#{value1} has viewed your "#{value2}""
```

How can I implement this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your expected result is invalid. Also it looks as if you want to add three quotes. It is not clear how that relates to your claim that you want to put `value2` in quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
text = %Q|#{value1} has viewed your "#{value2}"|
text = "#{value1} has viewed your \"#{value2}\""
```

or even:

```
text = "#{value1} has viewed your" '"' "#{value2}" '"'
```

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).